# Can someone lead me to what I'm talking about or make a proof This was just a thought in my head

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For every real number n, if there are real numbers a and b such that a+b=n, then ab is less than or equal to (n/2)^2

I'm more than certain that this is a common idea but I really wouldn't know what to look up to research more. Also, if you wanted to give an algerbraic or geometric proof that'd be cool

I thought this at night while laying in bed, I did 23x17 in my head and realized its close to 20x20 then realized that no combination was greater than or equal to 20x20. thanks for helping =)

Comment: You need to look up AM-GM inequality

Comment: $ab=a(n-a)=an-a^2=(n/2)^2-(a^2-na+(n/2)^2)=(n/2)^2-(a-(n/2))^2\le(n/2)^2$.

Comment: $23 \cdot 17 = (20+3)(20-3)= 20\cdot 20 - 3\cdot 3 < 20 \cdot 20$

Comment: This is equivalent to the statement that the rectangle with maximum area for a given perimeter is a square.